# How do I make the wifi-password unreachable on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, passwords, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I'm using Raspberry Pis for a department store. Because of the new GDPR I have to make the Raspberry Pis completely safe. So if someone potentially steals one of them, he absolutely can't access to anything. The Raspberries themselves play videos from a server, so they need to be connected to the wifi. Does anyone have an idea how I can protect the password of the wifi or maybe just delete the... "login-protocol" or something like that? Or do I need to use a second network?

Thanks and Greetings,
Elias

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wpa_passphrase` to obscure the WiFi password, which would throw up a big (but not absolute*) obstacle to someone who grabbed the Pi, pulled out the SD card, and rummaged through it for sekret stuff.

A safer move might be to treat the Pi as an inherently insecure device. Put an access point on a network segment that only has access to the videos you want to show, and give the Pi those credentials. If someone nabs the Pi and tears the SD card apart, all they'll find are credentials that let them attach to the store WiFi and watch the same videos.

* A determined attacker can run a 'dictionary attack' to try to generate the psk formed from the SSID and the pass phrase. Time consuming and slow to succeed if you have a long, strong WiFi password, but if your requirements are to be "completely safe", and you're liable to get in to long arguments with auditors, `wpa_passphrase` might not be worth the hassle.

Comment: I already made an Access Point and a Special Segment just for the Raspberry Pis. So if someone steals them now, he should only be able to find out the WiFi-Password and get access to the folder with the videos. So it's really just about the WiFi-Password. Is there any way to like "hash" it or something like that?

Comment: Read https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md and follow the example.